# Is it possible to get list of stored procs which only read data?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2012.
You can get a list of stored procs using TSQL like this :

```
select * from information_schema.routines r where r.ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
```

Is there a way to only get a subset of the stored procs which only read data (i.e. don't attempt INSERT or UPDATE statements within them, or any stored procs that they invoke).

I'm thinking the answer to this question is no, but just throwing it in here just in case.

The end goal is to try to create a database role which can only READ data in the database, and not modify it. The db_datareader role helps, but would also like to be able to call stored procs which only read data. The last resort is to grant execute permission on each stored proc.

Comment: wouldn't the methods that try writing just miserablly fail to perform the INSERT/UPDATE ?

Comment: @TomerW not always: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181362.aspx   - good suggestion though; you could just iterate over all objects in a `TRY...CATCH` and log the failures/successes.

Comment: @TomerW - No. If you grant `EXEC` to a stored procedure then ownership chaining can apply which means it doesn't check the permissions on the base tables.

Comment: @TomerW - no, I just tried it and the stored proc which does an INSERT succeeded. The user was a member of db_datareader role, and had execute permission on the stored proc.

Comment: Maybe Parse the Text of the SP Search for INSERT and UPDATE words? 
+ Recursive call for SP Calls ? another wiered idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adapted my queries above for SQL Server 2012 (thx @gvee).

```
select o.name, ref.name, refc.name, * 
from sys.sql_expression_dependencies d 
inner join sys.objects o on o.object_id = d.referencing_id
inner join sys.objects ref on d.referenced_id = ref.object_id
left outer join sys.columns refc 
    on d.referenced_id = refc.object_id 
        and d.referenced_minor_id = refc.column_id
order by 1, 2, 3


select o.name,  OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(o.object_id), *
from sys.objects o
where o.type = 'P' and o.name not in ('sp_upgraddiagrams')
and not exists (
    select 1
    from  sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities(
        OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(o.object_id) + '.' + o.name, 'OBJECT')
    where is_updated = 1
)
order by 1
```

Note that `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities` does not return the `is_updated` column in SQL 2008.

Querying for `sp_upgraddiagrams` will raise an error, but still return a result set.

Comment: great stuff, this actually seems to work ! I had to add some recursive CTE code to handle the case of stored procs calling other stored procs, but so far so good.

Comment: edge case - "is_updated" does not get set to 1 for "TRUNCATE TABLE" statements. Since TRUNCATE TABLE is rarely used, I can get by this with an exceptions table. I don't suppose there's any code which can detect if a stored proc calls TRUNCATE TABLE (other than text searching) ?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your stored procedure coding is consistent (e.g. you always use `EXEC` to explicitly call stored procedures rather than just its name) then you can get a good start using the following code.

```
SELECT Object_Name(object_id)
     , *
FROM   sys.sql_modules
WHERE  definition NOT LIKE '%EXEC %'
AND    definition NOT LIKE '%INSERT%'
AND    definition NOT LIKE '%UPDATE%'
AND    definition NOT LIKE '%DELETE%'
AND    definition NOT LIKE '%MERGE%'
```

Comment: UPDATE twice, but no DELETE? :)  Also, the OP may have the desire to allow SPs that Exec other SPs that are themselves also read only.  I think the OP is just on a painful road to manual checks, with a risk of future changes causing problems.

Comment: @MatBailie copy-paste error ;) Very good point on the chaining. This code was merely for illustrative purposes and provides a starting point and definitely not the complete end goal!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether the catalog view `sys.sql_dependencies` can always be relied on, but using the statement

```
select o.name, ref.name, refc.name, * 
from sys.sql_dependencies d 
inner join sys.objects o on o.object_id = d.object_id
inner join sys.objects ref on d.referenced_major_id = ref.object_id
left outer join sys.columns refc 
    on d.referenced_major_id = refc.object_id 
        and d.referenced_minor_id = refc.column_id
where is_updated = 1
order by 1, 2, 3
```

you can find out which objects modify others.

Based on this query, we can SELECT the stored procedures *not* marked with the is_updated flag:

```
select o.name
from sys.objects o
where o.type = 'P' and o.object_id not in (
    select d.object_id from sys.sql_dependencies d where is_updated = 1
)
order by 1
```

Comment: Just FYI: "This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. Use sys.sql_expression_dependencies instead." SOURCE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174402.aspx